# Custom dynamic inventory scripts/plugins in Ansible

Tags: json, ansible, inventory, vsphere

[Ansible allows devs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html)
 to write programs (in any language) that will return JSON describing the dynamic “snapshot” of current hosts. I’m using vSphere, which is currently not supported by Ansible OSS, and so I need to write such a "*custom inventory plugin*".

I can handle the querying of vSphere for a list of hosts, as well as constructing the JSON that is compatible with what Ansible is expecting.

Where the documentation completely (seemingly) falls flat is:

- How do I “connect” Ansible with my inventory app? That is, say my inventory app is a simple bash script (`inventory.sh`)..how do I configure Ansible to call `bash inventory.sh` and obtain JSON from it? In reality the app will likely be a Java executable (`inventory.jar`) but I figure that if I can figure out how to get it working with bash, I can extrapolate to Java; and
- How does Ansible actually capture/fetch the JSON back from the app? `STDOUT`? Is this all supposed to happen over an HTTP connection? Examples? How does `inventory.sh` or `inventory.jar` communicate that JSON back to Ansible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inventory script has to be located on the same machine where Ansible runs. It is not communicating through http, Ansible will simply parse the `STDOUT` of your program. The location does not matter at all, you have to pass the path to Ansible when you call Ansible:

```
ansible-playbook ... -i /path/to/your/inventory.sh
```

To avoid passing the inventory location every time you could [add this to you ansible.cfg](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#inventory):

```
inventory = /path/to/your/inventory.sh
```

You could also copy the script to `/etc/ansible/hosts`, which is the default location Ansible will look for inventory files/scripts, but I prefer to keep things together so I suggest to place it close to your playbooks/roles etc.

> And (3) Is any of this documented, anywhere? Don't see anything in the Ansible docs...

It is not mentioned on the page [Developing Dynamic Inventory Sources](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html) but it is to be seen on some examples on the page [Dynamic Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html). The docs are community managed and from times litte unstructured and lacking important information.

BTW, there is a [VMware inventory](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware.py) script included. By looking at the source I have seen it imports some vSphere stuff. I have little experience with VMware so I can't judge if this is actually what you need and don't need to write your own.

Comment: Awesome, perfect answer @udondan! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is completely user defined. Typically you would write your dynamic inventory in Python and use a json dump of the output to create the inventory.

Here is an example for the use case you mentioned (vSphere): https://github.com/RaymiiOrg/ansible-vmware/blob/master/query.py

In a nutshell you create it like a normal Python file and create the options (as he does in **main**) and selectively execute functions based on which options are passed. These will make REST calls and return the output in the form of a JSON dump, which Ansible can parse for use in inventory.

Comment: Thanks @kcrumpto (+1) - that script definitely helps, but still doesn't address my main concerns: (1) how do I configure Ansible to use this Python script/app for obtaining dynamic host list? And (2) How does this script/app communicate the JSON back? You mentioned JSON dumps, which I assume you mean [this](https://github.com/RaymiiOrg/ansible-vmware/blob/master/query.py#L73)? If so, it looks like the script is just sending the JSON dump to `STDOUT`, so does that mean Ansible is hooking `STDOUT`? Are the any other options here besides `STDOUT`?

Comment: And (3) Is *any* of this documented, *anywhere*? Don't see anything in the Ansible docs...